# How do you prevent direct access to a file in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'd like to stop the user from directly accessing the files in a directory via their URL, but would still like to be able to use them inside a PHP program via `include` or `require` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mention the below line in your `.htaccess` file. It'll definitely solve your problem.

```
RewriteRule ^includes/ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks is work for me, I can use include function and on direct access Object no found.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to put a `.php` file outside of the public_html folder. For example, if your public_html folder is at `/my/domain/public_html/` you could put your PHP files in `/my/domain/php_files/` and still access it from scripts within the public_html folder by using absolute or relative paths, but since it is outside of the public folder it will not be accessible over the web.

Keeping files outside of the public document folder is recommended best practice for configuration files etc. for security reasons.

Comment: yes that is working But still is there any other wayouts

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files conf.inc.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: not working, I still can access the PHP file in side the folder